# Regular expression to replace multiple occurances of a characters leaving one by a blank

Tags: regex, solr, wildcard

I want to implement wild card query in solr. I want that when I search for `query= ****diamond`, it should search for whiltediamond etc. ie all `'*'` should be replaced by `''` (blank) except 1 `*` ie. it should run as `*diamond`, I am using

```
query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 * ? :  .]+/g,'');
```

It means other than `*`, `?`, `:`, `.` it is replacing all special characters by a ''. now i want to convert it as that it should replace all `*` leaving one `*` by `''`.
Than what should be regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex should do the following:
Replace any number of asterisks by only one asterisk:

```
query=query.replace(/\*+/,'*');
```

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth:what is "/g" here